# Rendering performance in case of embedded containers

Tags: c++, qt, rendering, x11, xlib

I have an application which displays a web-cam output in a widget using SDL. I am getting output of order of 20-25 frames per second with this.

This output is then embedded into a QX11EmbedWidget container created in another process.
( or in another implementation using XLib I re-parented this output of SDL window to a native X11 window ).

Output I am obtaining in this case is around 2-5 frames per second.

Platform: Ubuntu on I.MX-53

Q1. Can some give an explanation of this difference in performance for these two cases.

Q2. When we embed an application's output into another's window, is it that rendering happens twice ? Once, by the application which is getting embedded, and then by the applications in which this window was embedded ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q1. Can some give an explanation of this difference in performance for these two cases.

No, not really. Maybe embedding the SDL windows doesn't work. Or a bug in X server on your platform. It can be anything.

> Q2. When we embed an application's output into another's window, is it that rendering happens twice? Once, by the application which is getting embedded, and then by the applications in which this window was embedded?

No, the rendering is done only in the window that is embedded.

Embedding the window is only going to change the parent.

> This output is then embedded into a QX11EmbedWidget container created in another process.

You should be using [QX11EmbedContainer](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qx11embedcontainer.html) as a container, not QX11EmbedWidget.

Comment: @V Jovic Suppose I have applications A and B both in Qt and embed A's output into B. If I miss out calling widget1.show() in app A [which I believe internally starts rendering for it?] , then I dont get to see the output even if I render the second application? And sorry, I wrote QX11EmbedWidget by mistake.

Comment: @AmitTomar You must call `show()` on the container (otherwise you'll not see anything).

Comment: @V Jovic If I call show() on only container and not the widget embedded, I see nothing. If I call it only for the widget embedded and not on container, then also I see nothing. If I call it for both, only then I see the output. Shouldnt I infer from this that rendering is being done in both container and widget embedded ?

Comment: @AmitTomar Not I am confused. You said that you create a window using SDL, and then you embed it using QX11EmbedContainer. You **must** call `show()` on the QX11EmbedContainer object. And you **must** render something in the SDL window. If you do not do that, you will not see anything.

Comment: @AmitTomar If you use qt widget to create a window, then `show()` is going to call `XMapWindow` on it. Without it, it will not be visible. Calling `show` on QX11EmbedContainer, it will make it visible (unless it is a window, where it will also call `XMapWindow` on it). So, you must call `show` on both